# How many thread worker are in a ForkJoinPool?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, fork-join

How can I know how many thread does a `ForkJoinPool` have? Let's say the `ThreadForkJoinPool` implementation.

I have a dual core.

Second quick question: Does synchronization (locks) work also with parallelism?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

However many you create it with, as per the Javadoc.  If you use the [default constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#ForkJoinPool%28%29):

> `public ForkJoinPool()`
>
> Creates a ForkJoinPool with parallelism equal to Runtime.availableProcessors(), using the default thread factory, no UncaughtExceptionHandler, and non-async LIFO processing mode.

If you use the [`int` constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#ForkJoinPool%28int%29):

> `public ForkJoinPool(int parallelism)`
>
> Creates a ForkJoinPool with the indicated parallelism level, the default thread factory, no UncaughtExceptionHandler, and non-async LIFO processing mode.

Please read the documentation before asking questions, and only ask one question at a time.

Comment: The docs don't mention how to set or know the number of threads.
They only mention "parallelism level" without explaining what this term really means.